# Ballistics Library

Tags: c#, java, .net, vb.net, math

Does anyone know if there has been a port of the GNU Ballistics library to C#, java, vb, etc?  Is there a similar library out there in any other language, even C++?

Answer (score 3):

Closest that I can think of for .NET is the bullet physics .NET port: http://bulletphysics.org/wordpress/

I've used it and liked it (in XNA).

Answer (score 0):

The Ballistics calculator for Android appears to include a Java port of the GNU Ballistics Library:
http://ballcalc.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/ballcalc/trunk/libballistics.java/src/ballistics/